# What location do OSX/Cocoa applications generally use to store data files?

Tags: cocoa, macos, bundle

Do they write/store them within the app bundle/package itself? Or some other canonical location? Or does there not seem to be any standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac app data is now stored in `~/Library/Containers/YOUR-APP`.

Answer (score 18):

Files usually go in `~/Library/Application Support/Your App/`.  Preferences go in `~/Library/Preferences/`.

Comment: Unless your app is document-based, in which case you store each document file where the user told you to. Also, you should never need to manage your own preferences files; user defaults does that for you. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/

Answer (score 10):

NEVER modify a file inside your own app bundle.

Comment: Why not? what is the problem, can you give a referrence?

Answer (score 4):

You should decidedly *not* write files into your app bundle at runtime. There's no guarantee that a user running your app will have permission to modify it. As Chris said, support files go in Application Support and preferences go in ~/Library/Preferences. To find the user's Application Support folder, you can use the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` function. To write preference files, you can use the NSUserDefaults or CFPreferences APIs.