# Where is the correct place to store a Mac application's database?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I'm building an application that I hope to submit to the Mac App Store.  The app has an SQL database that stores all of the items that the user has created.

Does anyone know where I should be storing this to comply with Apple's guidelines?  Should it go in Application Support, the Documents folder, the Library or somewhere else??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't automatically create file in the user home directory, except in `~/Library/Application Support/<Application>`. So either let the user choose where to store the information (if it is document centric), or store it in Application Support.

See the question: [What location do OSX/Cocoa applications generally use to store data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016596/what-location-do-osx-cocoa-applications-generally-use-to-store-data-files)